Capture NVRAM Data, while some other process using it
I'm trying to capture NVRAM Data while some other processes are using it and resulting it in inconsistent data and after uploading it getting NVRAM Corrupt Crash. Need a way to capture it.
It's bit impossible to create a Mutex as there are multiple process around 10+ process using it, internally there are even more files using it.
Have tried to collect it normally without suspending the process, resulting in corrupt. Is it right to suspend and resume it after capturing NVRAM data, is it ideal way of using? In my case, it might result in getting crash.
Edit 1: Platform Windows, high processes using it because of having custom OS based on Windows for running games

What platform?  On our embedded system, we had different types of NVRAM, including Flash and MRAM (magnetic).  We used mutexes to verify that no task wrote to the memory while another task was reading.

Using a lock may solve issue : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock
